# Logistic equation and Cauchy - Lipschitz theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I consider the following differential equation

$$
x’(t)= rx(t)(1-\frac{x(t)}{K})
$$

Where $r$ and $K$ are constant.

I consider an initial condition $x(0)=x_0\in (0,K)$.

In my lecture notes, it is written that given this initial condition and by the uniqueness of the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem we must have $x(t)\in (0,K)$ (and $x(t)$ constant equals to $K$ for $t\geq K$).

I don’t see how to make the link between this initial condition and the codomain of $x$ neither why we are restricted to $(0,K)$ ?

I have just noticed that when the derivative is $0$ (hence constant) we have $x(t)=K$, but I do not see how it prevents $x(t)$ to vary for $t\geq K$.

If you have any hint or explanations to give to me I will be glad.

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $t\le K$ derivative is positive and $x'(t)$ is increasing with respect to $x(t)$.
When $t \ge K$ derivative is negative and $x'(t)$ is decreasing with respect to $x(t)$.
So as a sample solution, we can plot $x'(t)$as below
[image]
and $x(t)$ like below
[image]

Hope that helps you.
Anf finally about $x=k$ it's the maximum point of $x',x$ graph like below
[image]

Comment: Very helpful thank you a lot !